# Prove that the domain of unbounded self-adjoint operator is strictly larger than that of its square

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, adjoint-operators

This is the problem from the textbook `Unbounded Self-adjoint Operators on Hilbert Space` by `Konrad Schmudgen`

Let $A$ be a self-adjoint operator which is not bounded. Show that there exists a vector $x \in \mathcal{D}(A)$ such that $x \notin \mathcal{D}\left(A^2\right)$.

If $A$ is bounded, it seems like $x \in \mathcal{D}(A)$ implies $x \notin \mathcal{D}\left(A^2\right)$. However, I don't know how to solve this problem. Should I find a counterexample or show this using the standard inner product technique?

Comment: If $A$ is bounded, $D(A) = \mathcal H$ by the usual definition of a bounded operator, so $Ax \in \mathcal H = D(A)$ which is to say $x \in D(A^2)$.

Comment: Is spectral theorem for ubounded self-adjoint operators available for this exercise ?

Comment: Yes. This exercise is the problem from the spectral theorem chapter.